# Interrupting MediaPlayer

Tags: android, media-player

My application makes a short announcement once in a while, either via `TextToSpeech` or using the `MediaPlayer`. If there is some other music running in the background probably by some application using the `MediaPlayer`, I would like to interrupt this music for a moment and after my announcement resume playing the "background music".

Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you can target API level 8 and above (Android 2.2), then have a look into the [AudioManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html), specifically [`requestAudioFocus()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html#requestAudioFocus(android.media.AudioManager.OnAudioFocusChangeListener,%20int,%20int)) with `AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN_TRANSIENT` and `AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN_TRANSIENT_MAY_DUCK`, and [`abandonAudioFocus()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html#abandonAudioFocus(android.media.AudioManager.OnAudioFocusChangeListener)).

These give hints to the currently-playing music stream that your app would like to play a brief sound. If you use `AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN_TRANSIENT_MAY_DUCK` with `requestAudioFocus()` you can get a nice effect where the already-playing music pauses, your sound plays, and then the playing music fades back in again when you call `abandonAudioFocus()`.

This works nicely with the built-in media players on the 2.2 devices I've tried it with (Samsung Galaxy S Wi-Fi and HTC Wildfire.) I've not tried it extensively with other music-playing apps, but it definitely works with Spotify, at least, and is the official way of doing exactly what you want to do.

Note that you'll need to work out for yourself when to call `abandonAudioFocus()` as most sounds are played asynchronously. Luckily, both `MediaPlayer` and `TextToSpeech` provide callback mechanisms so they can give you a prod when they've finished playing your sound (this *isn't* true of `SoundPool`, so that's more annoying to use audio focus with.)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a standard way to do it for every music player out there. At least for the Android music player you could do:

```
Intent i;
i = new Intent("com.android.music.musicservicecommand");
i.putExtra("command", "pause");
context.sendBroadcast(i);
```

Another way to do it would be to set the stream volume for type "music" to 0, and play your announcement on another stream type.