# Controlling Google Music Beta app from my app?

Tags: android, api, controls

So I'm working on a project right now for Android and was curious as to how I would go about controlling Google Music and/or Goole Music Beta (skipping, play, pause, etc.) from my app. Is there a universal skip/play/pause control mechanism in Android or do i directly have to communicate with the music app through intents (and if so some documentation or a tutorial would be nice)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The solution suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6383862/interrupting-mediaplayer/6383921#6383921) works with the Google Music app:

```
String command = "togglepause";
Intent i = new Intent("com.android.music.musicservicecommand");
i.putExtra("command", command);
sendBroadcast(i);
```

I haven't been able to find a list of all available commands, but play, pause, previous, next seem to work.